# Ensure ALL iPhone burst shoot images are shared via upload

Tags: iphone, photos, data-transfer

How do I ensure that ALL iPhone burst shoot images are shared via upload for Selection & Editing?

iPhone 8 iOS 13.4.1

- We did a casual photo shoot, with lots of burst shots a few months back.

  - We never got around to working on the pictures together nor did the photographer get to move them off his iPhone.
- I know it’s possible for the photographer to upload the pics to a cloud drive/ folder such as Dropbox/ Google Drive / OneDrive/ pcloud. I use them a lot for non photography files.
- **The issue now is there's something about Burst mode that all images from that burst sequence are not uploaded or shared. How do we make this happen?**

I wonder if there’s a better way for the photographer to upload & share with me while we can work on it online itself?

- Without me having to download all of them for working on them on my iPhone or Windows based Surface Pro.

We might need to do a repeat of this in the future & again work remotely from each other.

**Is there a better photo selection & editing workflow here?**

Ps: I am a tech geek but not regular with such shoot & workflows.